# StackOverflowError on querydsl when deploying war

Tags: java, jdbctemplate, querydsl, stack-overflow

The war works well in local and on a server test.
But when deploying the war on a new server app, I get the following error:

```
 GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/App] threw exception [java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.mysema.query.types.Templates.getTemplate(Templates.java:228)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:218)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.SQLSerializer.visitOperation(SQLSerializer.java:559)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:199)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:26)
    at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:44)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:83)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:244)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.SQLSerializer.visitOperation(SQLSerializer.java:559)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:199)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:26)
    at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:44)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:83)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:244)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.SQLSerializer.visitOperation(SQLSerializer.java:559)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:199)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:26)
    at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:44)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:83)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:244)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.SQLSerializer.visitOperation(SQLSerializer.java:559)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:199)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:26)
    at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:44)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:83)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:244)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.SQLSerializer.visitOperation(SQLSerializer.java:559)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:199)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:26)
    at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:44)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:83)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:244)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.SQLSerializer.visitOperation(SQLSerializer.java:559)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:199)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:26)
    at com.mysema.query.types.expr.BooleanOperation.accept(BooleanOperation.java:44)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:83)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:244)
    at com.mysema.query.sql.SQLSerializer.visitOperation(SQLSerializer.java:559)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:199)
    at com.mysema.query.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:26)
```

The querydsl version used is: 2.2.2. 
No exception related to my code is raised !

Comment: 2.2.2 is a very old version. Try upgrading to 3.2.4.